# Can I leave the station with a Belarus transit visa?

Tags: uk-citizens, transit-visas, belarus

I'm a UK passport holder planning to travel by train from Warsaw to Moscow via Minsk next June.  As I have a little slack in my time table, I'm thinking of catching the sleeper from Warsaw to Minsk one night, followed by the Minsk to Moscow sleeper the next night.  This will give me a day to explore Minsk.  Can I do this with a transit visa?  Or will I then be unable to leave the station?  (If it affects the answer, the two border crossings -- from Poland, and to Russia -- are unlikely to be on the same day.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can leave the station. The period of validity is said to be two days on their official embassy sites in both the US and [UK](http://mfa.gov.by/en/visa/), so you should be okay leaving the next day.

[image]

Comment: How would you interpret "valid for 2 days from the date of entry"?  If I enter the country shortly before midnight on the 18th, can I leave shortly after midnight on 20th?  (Though I think probably that won't happen as probably the first border crossing will be after midnight.)

Comment: I don't know how exactly they interpret it. You might want to ring the embassy if this is an issue. 'Two days' may or may not be the same as '48 hours'.

Comment: @RichardSmith, '2 days' universally means the day of arrival and the day of departure with zero days between them. But there is no passport control between Belarus and Russia, thus there will be nobody to notice when you actually left Belarus.

Comment: The information I've received officially agrees with @AndreyChernyakhovskiy.  If I enter the country at 10pm on 18th and leave the country at 1am on 20th, I cannot properly use a transit visa.  (However I expect you're right that they wouldn't notice.)